# What is the maximum modulus of a dot product over the distinguished boundary of the standard polydisc?

Tags: calculus, optimization, several-complex-variables

Let $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{C}^2$.

For each $\mathbf{c} = (c_1, c_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2$, what is the maximum value of
$$|\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{z}|= |c_1 \exp(-it_1) + c_2 \exp(-it_2)|$$
as $\mathbf{z}$ ranges over all vectors $(\exp(it_1), \exp(it_2)) \in S^1 \times S^1$ perpendicular to $\mathbf{a}$?

Comment: What role does a play?

Comment: $\mathbf{a}$ is a constant. I guess, by symmetry, $\mathbf{a}$ may be taken to be of the form $(w, 0)$.

Comment: Choose a unitary matrix $U$ such that the second component of $a U $ is equal to zero. Then the first component of $z U $ is equal to zero. Hence $|c \cdot z| = |c U  \cdot z U | = |(c U )_2 \overline{(z U )_2}| = |(c U )_2| |(z U )_2|$. Since $(z U)_2 = z_1 U_2^1  + z_2 U_2^2$ -- where $U_j^i$ denotes the $(i,j)$th entry of $U$ -- the triangle inequality implies that $ |(z U )_2|  \le |z_1 U_2^1 | + |z_2 U_2^2 | = |U_2^1| + |U_2^2|$ for $z \in S^1 \times S^1$. Therefore $|c \cdot z| \le |(c U )_2|(|U_2^1| + |U_2^2|)$.

Comment: Set $U = (1/\| a\|)\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a_1 & \overline{a_2} \\ a_2 & -\overline{a_1}\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, checking that indeed $(a U)_2 = a_1 U_2^1 + a_2 U_2^2 = (1/\|a\|)(a_1 \overline{a_2} + a_2 (-\overline{a_1})) = 0$, then the upper bound of $|c \cdot z|$ is given intrinsically by $|(c U)_2| (|U^1_2| + |U^2_2|) = (1/\|a\|)|c_1 \overline{a_2} + c_2 (-\overline{a_1})|\times (1/\|a\|)(|\overline{a_2}| + |-\overline{a_1}|) = (1/\| a\|^2)|c_1\overline{a_2} - c_2 \overline{a_1}|(|a_2| + |a_1|)$.